# Android Picture Ambilight

Tags: android, image, colors, background

I have a pretty specific Question and i hope anyone can give me reference to some further Documentation if it should exist.

Im building a Slideshow with ~ 10 Pictures. I found awesome HTML5 / CSS styles to accomplish ambilight background. And i was asking, if there is any chance to do this in ANDROID too ?

Examples can be found here:

http://ajaxian.com/archives/ambilight

http://codepen.io/MyXoToD/pen/KbADu

For the lazy ppl who dont click the links, short summary:

**Centered Image in the middle and "ambilight" colors as background around it.**

Appreciate your thoughts :)

Comment: The javascript in http://ajaxian.com/archives/ambilight can be easily converted to Native Java code for android..

Comment: Collecting the right colors is working fine, but still the Problem I am facing is, that i cannot map these to my canvas. I know how to use shapes etc. But this is way to much work, is there any Matrix or something similar to map "gradients" to a canvas?